# What is the difference between 生む and 産む?

Tags: word-choice

The question has been asked before but I found the answer is too complicated.

Comment: I agree that the answer does not provide much clarity. A better one could be formulated. 
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13316/whats-the-difference-between-%e7%94%9f%e3%82%80-and-%e7%94%a3%e3%82%80

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between 生む and 産む?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13316/whats-the-difference-between-%e7%94%9f%e3%82%80-and-%e7%94%a3%e3%82%80)